# insert from two named graphs?

Tags: sparql, graphdb, named-graphs

**I'm looking for an easy way to insert triples from two or more named graphs (but not the entire unnamed default graph) into another named graph.**  I'm using GraphDB.

*I guess this could be done by writing out the same query multiple times in the `WHERE` section, wrapped in multiple  `GRAPH` specifications, and then unioning them together, but my `WHERE`s are long and I'd prefer not to write them out multiple times.*

Let's say I have loaded some data like this:

```
INSERT DATA {
  GRAPH <http://example.com/ngA> {
    <http://example.com/person1> <http://example.com/name> "Arthur" .
  }
  GRAPH <http://example.com/ngB> {
    <http://example.com/person1> <http://example.com/name> "Brian" .
  }
  GRAPH <http://example.com/ngC> {
    <http://example.com/person1> <http://example.com/name> "Charlie" .
  }
}
```

I can copy all of the triples of a certain pattern from the default unnamed graph into a new named graph with something like this:

```
INSERT {
  GRAPH <http://example.com/ngZ> {
    ?s <http://example.com/moniker> ?o .
  }
}
WHERE
  { ?s  <http://example.com/name>  ?o }
```

An easy way to `SELECT` for triples of a given pattern from two or more (but not all) named graphs is

```
SELECT  *
FROM <http://example.com/ngA>
FROM <http://example.com/ngB>
WHERE
  { ?s  <http://example.com/name>  ?o }
```

What if I want to copy those triples, from those specified graphs, into another graph?

I'm getting an error from GraphDB 8.3 (and from the sparql.org validator) when I try to

```
INSERT {
  GRAPH <http://example.com/ngZ> {
    ?s <http://example.com/moniker> ?o .
  }
}
WHERE
  { SELECT  *
FROM <http://example.com/ngA>
FROM <http://example.com/ngB>
WHERE
  { ?s  <http://example.com/name>  ?o } }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this query:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/>

INSERT {
  GRAPH ex:ngZ { ?s ex:moniker ?o }
}
WHERE {
  GRAPH ?g { ?s ex:name ?o }  
  FILTER (?g IN ( ex:ngA, ex:ngB ) )
}
```

And then:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/>

SELECT * 
FROM NAMED ex:ngZ
WHERE { 
    GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o }
} LIMIT 100
```

Is it what you need?

By the way, there exist [`COPY`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#copy) (use with caution!) and [`ADD`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#add).

Answer (score 5):

[SPARQL Update](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert) provides `USING` and `USING NAMED` analogous to `FROM` and `FROM NAMED` in queries:

> The USING and USING NAMED clauses affect the RDF Dataset used while evaluating the WHERE clause. This describes a dataset in the same way as FROM and FROM NAMED clauses

You can express the requirement as an UPDATE like so:

```
INSERT {
  GRAPH <http://example.com/ngZ> {
    ?s <http://example.com/moniker> ?o .
  }
}
USING <http://example.com/ngA>
USING <http://example.com/ngB>
WHERE
  {  ?s  <http://example.com/name>  ?o }
```

Also note that, according to the [SPARQL query grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rSubSelect), a subquery does not admit a dataset clause. This is why the SPARQL parsers are rejecting your query.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, @Stanislav Kralin

Come to think of it, this also works:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/>
INSERT {
    GRAPH ex:ngZ {
        ?s ex:moniker ?o 
    }
}
WHERE {
    values ?g {
        ex:ngA ex:ngB 
    }
    GRAPH ?g {
        ?s ex:name ?o 
    }  
}
```